# Возможно ли ввести в консоль строку, содержащую в середине символ конца строки?

Tags: c++, строки, консоль

Возможно ли ввести в консоль приложения C++, допустим в Linux, строку вида

"aaaa\0aaa"

и поймать ее в помощью fscanf или std::cin.get() или std::getline()?
Т.е. Возможно ли каким либо образом считать с консоли за один вызов функции в буфер последовательность симолов, содержащую в середине нулевой символ?

Comment: `write` `read`, не?

Comment: При вводе \0 - не будет введен символ с кодом ноль - будет введено два символа, с кодами 47 (поделить) и 48 (ноль десятичный).. Думаю ввести нолевой символ - будет достаточно проблематично, либо нужно наверняка знать как. Нулевой символ имеет большое значение при использовании строк формата ASCIIZ.

Comment: А Вы попробуйте ввести нуль-символ в консоли, а потом расскажите нам, что не получается с ним сделать.

Comment: Нулевой символ имеет большое значение при использовании строк формата ASCIIZ, если вы используете ф-ции ASCIIZ для работы с файлом, то если попадётся ноль - будет "обрезание данных" (не верная интерпретация данных), поэтому файлы делят условно на текстовые (которые не содержат знак NULL ноль) и на двоичные. Для чтения двоичных файлов нужно write read. Но можно и по-одному символу get делать.

Comment: Сделать ввод с nil внутри --  без проблем. Что-то вроде `(echo -n abcd; dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null; echo -n 123) | hexdump -C`

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил, сам нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354228/how-to-input-a-string-to-c-with-null-character-in-it-via-gets

Есть комбинации клавиш, которые вводят нулевой символ, например Ctrl+Shift+2.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, стало интересно - зная данную комбинацию клавиш - как Вам удалось записать в буфер последовательность, содержащую в середине нулевой символ?

Comment: @isnullxbh,  `getline` спокойно читает нули в середине (кстати, GCC (сишная функция) [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) тоже)